# Play a movie in another app then return to my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, video

I wanted to be able to play a divx or mkv file from my app. So I'm using url schema method, calling a player like Buzz Player via

```
UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSString ourPath = @"http://buzzplayer:http://www.mylocalserver.com/file.avi";
NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
[ourApplication openURL:ourURL];
```

And that works great, it opens the file in the video player fine. But when I press Done in that player, it goes to the Buzz Player menu not back to my app.

It makes sense I guess as I did send the URL request to the player and I'm assuming this isn't Buzz Player specific but something any app would do.

Is there any way I can get an external player to work as the Apple built in video player works; when I press done it jumps back to my app? Or maybe a better solution to this?

I didn't want to reinvent the wheel and build a video player into my app when there are so many great apps that do this out there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get iOS to bring your app back to the front after the other app is done. In your case it seems you'll need to build a movie player into your app. Which isn't that hard to do. Have a look at the MediaPlayer class in the Foundation framework.

Comment: I'm currently using MediaPlayer and it works perfectly except for supported codecs, thats why I wanted to use an alternative player instead. Maybe I need to look around for a third party library I can embed in my app that can play AVI and MKV files?